# How does git detect that a file has been modified?

Tags: git

How does git detect a file modification so fast?

Does it hash every file in the repo and compare SHA1s?  This would take a lot of time, wouldn't it?

Or does it compare `atime`, `ctime` or `mtime`?

Comment: May be different for different platforms. I'm particularly interested in how Git/Windows does it

Answer (score 50):

Git tries hard to get convinced from the lstat() value alone that the worktree matches the index, because falling back on file contents is very expensive.

[Documentation/technical/racy-git.txt](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/racy-git.txt) describes what stat fields are used, and how some race conditions due to low mtime granularity are avoided. [This article has some more detail](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gg/race.html).

stat values aren't tamper-proof, see futimens(3). Git may be fooled into missing a change to a file; that does not compromise the integrity of content-hashing.

Comment: But does every commit fall back on file contents? Or is it guessing even at commit?

Comment: @Pacerier git uses [Merkel Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) to quickly compute the hash of an entire repo without needing to hash every file all-over-again. The only requirement is that git knows _which_ files are modified so it knows what parts of the Merkel Tree it needs to recompute.

Answer (score 10):

There's an initial mtime check for reports like "git status", but when the final commit is computed, mtimes don't matter... it's the SHA1 that matters.

Comment: @Randal: I don't think this is true, it always does a diff: http://gist.github.com/240775.  If only mtime was used for `git status` you would see modifications in the paste I did.

Comment: @jkp My own strace-ing shows that unchanged worktree files only have `lstat` done to them.

Answer (score 6):

Well I would hazard a guess that it's using a combination of `stat()` calls to work out what looks like it might have changed, then in turn actually tying to ascertain using it's diff'ing engine that this is the case.

You can see the code for the diff engine [here](http://github.com/git/git/blob/a6dbf8814f433a7fbfa9cde6333c98019f6db1e4/diff-lib.c) to get some idea.  I traced through the codebase to be sure that the status command does indeed call down into this code (it looks like a lot of stuff does!) and actually all this makes a lot of sense when you know that Git performs pretty badly on Windows where it is using an emulation layer to perform these POSIX type calls: it's an order of magnitude slower to do a `git status` on that platform.

Anyway, short of reading all the code from top to bottom (which I may later if I have time!) thats as far as I can take you for now...maybe someone can be more definitive if they have worked with the codebase.

Note: another possible speedup comes from judicious use of `inline` functions where it clearly makes sense, you can see this clearly in the headers.

[edit: see [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/stat.html) for an explanation of `stat()`]

Comment: care to explain what `stat()` is/does?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on platform, you should be able to find out what syscalls Git uses to figure out its status. Try `strace git status` on Linux, `truss git status` on SunOS, or the seemingly DTrace-based tool that Apple ships with its Developer Tools on Mac OS X.