Why is "git add -A" so much slower than "git status"? And could I speed up my "git add"s by working from "git status" instead?
In git, I usually prefer to not use the staging area very much, and just work with my working tree. Call me crazy, but I don't get much use out of this extra step before committing, etc., of adding all the files to a staging area, then running git commit.
So whenever I want to create a new commit, I run git add -A && git commit ...
But git add -A is so slow! On my repo, it's taking 5-10 seconds to run!
I've noticed that git status is much faster - usually less than 1 second.

Why is git add -A so much slower? Since a regular git add is pretty fast, I always assumed what makes git add -A so slow is enumerating all the untracked files. But git status also has to do that, and it's fast.

Can I get the same effect as git add -A, but faster, by running git status and piping the output to git add? Something like (this won't be totally correct): git status -s | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | git add. Is there something else that git add -A is doing that I'm missing, and I'd have problems going this route?



git add -A will need to hash and store every file it adds; if you’re regularly adding large files or many files that will be slow. How big is your repository (in terms of number of files and total file size)?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075528/what-algorithm-does-git-use-to-detect-changes-on-your-working-tree

@nneonneo the repo is pretty large, hundreds of thousands of files, and a size of tens of MiB, according to 'git count-objects -vH'

@nneonneo I don't think the work of adding the files is causing the slowdown either. I just timed two commands: 'git add -A' and 'git status -s | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | xargs git add'. Both had just a single untracked file to add, no other modifications/deletions/etc. 'git add -A' took 8 seconds, the other command took 1.2s.

I am using watchman, from Meta, to speed up git operations. Maybe it's working for 'git status' but for some reason not being used for 'git add -A'

Please note that whatever command you execute first will be "slow". The second command can already rely on the data in the filesystem cache and the Git cache will be hot too.

Sure, I've seen that. I need to run 'git status' once to warm it up. That first 'git status' can take 5-10 seconds too, but subsequent runs are much faster (~1s). The 'git add -A' commands always take 5-10 seconds though.

I can't see right away where the time sink is. If you are on Linux, run strace -e file -tt -o /tmp/git.strace git add -A (it records file operations with timestamps), then inspect /tmp/git.strace for a hint where the time is spent.
