# How to change image tracking with Git?

Tags: image, git

In my Git repository I've got quite a lot of images (changing to other VCS then Git is out of the question).
Part of the images, are duplicates with a different size, these are created by ImageMagick. From time to time, I have to regenerate the images, which is ok, however, even though the image itself didn't change [size is the same etc] git marks this file as modified.
I assume this is because of last modified dates, is that right?
Is there any chance, I could change the way git tracks changes of images?
Is there anyway to add ImageMagick's compare functionality?

Answer (score 2):

### Edited

I was wrong, git avoid checking the file content and prefer using faster methods as described in the related post: [How does git detect that a file has been modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778862/how-does-git-detect-that-a-file-has-been-modified)

If your files are not modified, I'm not sure if I understand well, but maybe using [`git update-index --assume-unchanged`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit) might help.

However that does not mean your files are not modified when you re-run the generation step, and you should check for yourself with [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-files) or follow advices of the post [How can I diff binary files in git?](https://superuser.com/questions/706042/how-can-i-diff-binary-files-in-git)

But I think the problem does not lie with `git` and it would be better to review your work-flow.
I can see two options:

1. either you do not re-generate the images if it's not needed and by doing so you avoid the problem
2. or you do not track the binary files in git and generate them on the target

Comment: Thanks bufh, you are right, I didn't think of the meta. This is how I generate them: `${imgAnimationsDir}/*.jpg -resize 50% -set filename:fname '%t-sd.%e' +adjoin '${imgAnimationsDir}/%[filename:fname]'`

Comment: Is there any way I could get to know on what basis git decided the file was modified?