# Git not seeing small changes in images

Tags: git

I often need to update and push some images with git but the problem is that if the changes are minimal (e.g. change of a letter from 'C' to 'K' in the image content), git doesn't detect that something changed (the size of the image stays the same but the content is different). So, I cannot add the images that changed with git add... and when I push, it say that "Everything up-to-date". Is there a way to force files not detected to be pushed?

Comment: What do you mean with "changing a letter" in an image? You mean changing its filepath? or changes in content?

Comment: The content. Then the size of the file is the same but the content is different

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829216/how-to-change-image-tracking-with-git

Comment: *I often need to update and push some images*. You **should not** store binaries that change frequently in Git. Git cannot effectively diff binary content, so your repository size will quickly get out of control. This will turn into a huge problem for you down the line, so it's best to fix the problem before it gets out of hand. Use Git-LFS or a separate system designed for versioning binaries.

Comment: Thanks for the info but it's part of a huge workflow that has been set up for years before I work on this. They are small images that don't change frequently but are most of the time inserted or sometimes updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git push` command does not push files.  That's because Git does not *store* files—not at this level, anyway.  Git is all about *commits,* and Git stores *commits*, not files.  The commits then store files, so you might ask *what's the difference* ... and the difference is a lot.  In fact, it explains about half the problems people have with Git.

You need to know this about commits:

- Commits are *numbered*.  Each commit gets a unique *hash ID*, which is a big ugly random-looking number expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  When I say *unique*, I mean it: the number your new commit gets, when you make a new commit, is not allowed to be used for *any* other commit in *any* Git repository ever.<sup>1</sup>
- Commits are made up of two parts:

  - Each commit stores a full copy of every file.  These full copies are compressed and de-duplicated, which keeps the repository from getting bloated and making Git unusable.  Unfortunately, as [Daniel Mann noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70112784/git-not-seeing-small-changes-in-images#comment123941516_70112784), large binaries interfere with this and the repository may become unmanageable, so try to avoid storing images in Git if possible.
  - Each commit stores some *metadata*, such as the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  We won't go into detail here, but this metadata is crucial to Git's own internal operation.
- Commits—and all other internal Git objects—are *completely immutable*.  Once you make a commit, it's stuck that way forever.  *That* hash ID means *that commit*.  If you make a mistake in a commit, you can correct it with `git commit --amend`, but the `--amend` is a lie: what you're doing is making a new *replacement* commit, shoving the old commit aside.  Both commits remain in the repository for a while.  If nothing *uses* the old commit (and nothing does), it eventually "falls out" of the repository.  It doesn't normally get sent to any other Git either.  And with the de-duplication, each commit tends to be tiny: well under a disk "block", except for any all-new files (including image binaries).  So it's not really a big deal to have a few extra junk ones.

There's more to know, but the above will serve for now.  Because commits *are* immutable snapshots of files plus some metadata, you don't actually work on a commit.  Instead, you have Git *extract* the files *from* the commit, into a work area.  Git calls this your *working tree*.  Here you actually do have files—real, ordinary files, not the weird Git-ized "blob objects" that aren't really files that Git uses to store the files in commits—that you can use and work with.

When you modify or replace one of these working tree files, you use `git add` to tell Git that you've done so.  This *does not use the size of the file* as an indicator that the file is changed.<sup>2</sup>  It uses instead a whole bunch more metadata about the file as it existed at the time Git extracted it from the commit.  If *any* of that metadata have changed, Git will see the file as changed, and will be willing to update the file in its (Git's) *index*.

If Git *doesn't* update the file in its index, you've hit one of several possible conditions:

- The file isn't in the index now, and should not be in the index.  Running `git check-ignore -v path/to/file.ext` will tell you why Git thinks this is the case.  Running `git ls-files --stage path/to/file.ext` will tell you about the copy of the file that *is* in the index; if it says nothing, the file isn't in the index.
- The file is in the index, but is marked with `--skip-worktree` or `--assume-unchanged`.  You have to do this yourself unless you're using Git's "sparse checkout" mode, so you'd probably know if you had set these.  Technically, setting either flag manually is usually an abuse of the purpose of these flags, but people do abuse them for various effects, so it's worth mentioning here.
- Some software you're using is fiddling with the file metadata, for some reason.  That's probably a bad idea, but software that does this *can* fool Git.
- You've found a bug in Git.  This is pretty unlikely, but needs to be mentioned as a possibility, especially with the Git 2.34.0 bug with `.gitignore`.

You can get around these problems in various ways:

- adjust the `.gitignore` file contents if necessary / appropriate;
- clear the flags (using `git update-index` again) if you set them using `git update-index`;
- "force-add" the file with `git add -f`;
- remove the index content (`git rm --cached`) and add again or force-add;
- add with the `--renormalize` flag to bypass Git cleverness.

Some combination of these options will generally work.  In particular, removing with `git rm --cached` clears any flags you set manually and destroys the fancy metadata cache stuff that makes Git go fast, after which `git add -f` bypasses any `.gitignore`, so using those two commands would generally do the trick.  Using `git add --renormalize` bypasses Git's metadata caching and will do the trick if you have some overly-clever software that inappropriately sets the file metadata back after modifying the file.

Once the index copy is updated, a future `git commit` will make a new commit,<sup>3</sup> which you can then `git push` to another repository.

---

<sup>1</sup>That's why the number has to be so big.  If a collision happens, <s>the universe is destroyed</s> er wait <s>the wrong party gains political power</s> no, it's "those two Git repositories are not allowed to meet".  OK, not really all that drastic.  Still, it's a bad scene and nobody wants it.

<sup>2</sup>That's not quite true: if the size changed, the file definitely *did* change.  But the size isn't the most important thing here.

<sup>3</sup>A pre-commit hook *could* interfere with this, if you have one.  A pre-push hook could interfere with the `git push` step.

Comment: Thanks for these great explanations!