# How to use git to manage all website file?

Tags: git, version-control

We already use git to manage websites development in `.php` `.html` `.js`
Besides those,we have banner,logo files need to be managed.

I want an integrated file management tool to let me know the change of all websites files. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the besides files in **repo folder** or **subfolder**. And be sure, these type of files are not ignored by `.gitignore` file.

Comment: But I really want to manage the files like jpg,gif, any tool can be used?

Comment: Git is enough, you can use git to manage jpg or gif files. Such as you have 1.jpg in git and then replace a different picture as 1.jpg, git will treat it as different one, so it’s ok to control version by git.

Comment: how git can recognize jpg change?by timestamp or size?I am not sure if i can commit .jpg with tag

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778862/how-does-git-detect-that-a-file-has-been-modified, but be sure, git can detect the changes, so it’s ok to commit jpg with tag. Note: because jpg is binary file, so git diff can not compare the real changes.

Comment: Did you tried to use git to manage the files, and what's going on?